# onSubmit() call multiple time service

Tags: angular2-forms

I am write a form with some fields, when all have valid then i am enable the submit button, do a service call on onSubmit() method.My issue is when i click on the submit button twice it do service call twice. Is there any directive for check form submit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you click on the submit button twice it will call the service two times just use one variable 'submit' boolean by default false.

reference: https://angular.io/guide/forms#submit-the-form-with-ngsubmit

```
onSubmit() {
   if(this.submit) {
      return;
   }
   this.submit = true;
   this.serviceCall(); // got error set submit to false.
}
```